# Calling javascript code from code behind in vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

i'm working on a web project with asp.net and VB.Net.
I have inside a loop à javascript code let's say it's :

```
Do While Not oActivite.eof
strScript = "<script type='text/javascript'>"
strScript = strScript + "alert(" + strActiviteId + ");"
strScript = strScript + "</script>"
Loop
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, GetType(String), "tmp", strScript, False)
```

strScript is a string
And strActiviteId is a variable which value change in every loop.

When the page loads, i only get an alert with the first value of strActiviteId.
what i want is to get :

```
Alert(strActiviteIdFirstLoop);

Alert(strActiviteIdSecondtLoop);
...
```

But the problém is more than this, i have a bigger script instead of the alert, a jQuery script that adds a div containing a span and an input in front of a td.

and what i want is append to the div id the strActiviteId variable, before i would get divs with the same strActiviteId value in the id , but when i did what you told me, now i get three divs in front of each checkbox.

this is the jQuery code i put in the strScript :

```
$("#ctl00_indexBody_ID_ACTIVITE tbody tr td").after("
<span id='ctl00_indexBody_label1' >Tarif : </span> 
<input type='TEXT' 
onchange='ContenuModifier();' 
style='width: 270px;' id='N_PRIX' 
name='N_PRIX' onfocus='BeginSaisie(this,'99999')'
onblur='EndSaisie(this,'99999')' 
onkeypress=';CtrlSaisie(event,this,'99999')' maxlength='5' 
class='user_access_email bootstrapped-input input-text input-block-level         input-xlarge'>
");
```

I hope this is understandable, thank you for your help.

Ps : eof is a built in method that returns false when there is no data in oActivite which is an object i populated earlier.

Comment: there's no loop in your code. Please show the whole logic. The problem probably sits in the loop

Comment: Why do you use jQuery to build your markup? can't you simply use a `<asp:Reapeater>` ?

Comment: Because i want to give it the same id as the checkbox, and afterwards i want to hide it, and whenever the user checks the textbox appers in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

The first line :

```
strScript = "<script type='text/javascript'>"
```

resets the script value in each loop. And you register the script only after the do while loop. Only the last script value will be rendered.

Try this:

```
strScript = "<script type='text/javascript'>"
Do While Not oActivite.eof
strScript += "alert(" + strActiviteId + ");"
Loop
strScript += "</script>"
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, GetType(String), "tmp", strScript, False)
```

That said, you should consider using a StringBuilder depending on the loop count, to reduce string instantiation.

Comment: Im sorry if i look like i'm stalling you, but i asked the same question before and it was hard to answer, that's why i started with the alert example.